# Rollup Won't Bundle Proptypes Dependency

Tags: rollupjs

I'm trying to build a component library of react components. I'd like to keep my prop-types in the library as documentation rather than remove them at build time. The problem is that rollup doesn't bundle all of the prop-types functions.

I end up with these lines in my bundle:

```
var ReactPropTypesSecret = require('./lib/ReactPropTypesSecret');

var checkPropTypes = require('./checkPropTypes');
```

And the consumers of my library can't resolve those packages so it ends up in an error.

My rollup config looks like this:

```
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import pkg from "./package.json";

export default {
  input: "src/index.js",
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: "cjs",
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: "es",
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  external: Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies || {}),
  plugins: [
    babel(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs({ include: ["./index.js", "node_modules/**"] })
  ]
};
```

How can I force rollup to bundle and expand the `require('./lib/ReactPropTypesSecret')` call at build time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out this was due to two problems:

Ordering of Rollup plugins. Resolve should come first, followed by commonjs, and then babel.

Babel should exclude node_modules. Having Babel parse them might leave commonjs and resolve unable to parse them to bundle dependencies.

The final config should be:

```
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import pkg from "./package.json";

export default {
  input: "src/index.js",
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: "cjs",
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: "es",
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  external: Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies || {}),
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    babel({
      exclude: "**/node_modules/**"
    }),
    commonjs({ include: ["./index.js", "node_modules/**"] })
  ]
};
```

Comment: In your library's `package.json`, did you include `prop-types` within `peerDependencies` or within `dependencies`. Could you share the GitHub link to your library if it's open source? Thanks!

Comment: Bit late on this, but it's a bit more complicated now than when I had this problem, but you can see my rollup config here: https://github.com/hcikit/hcikit/blob/master/packages/tasks/rollup.config.js and my package.json: https://github.com/hcikit/hcikit/blob/master/packages/tasks/package.json

The repo is overall a bit messy because it's a monorepo but I hope this helps if it's not too late.

Answer (score 0):

- In your package.json, include 'prop-types' within 'peerDependencies'
- npm install

That fixed my problem:
[!] Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules\prop-types\index.js, imported by Component